# How can I check the sample email sent by PayPal Invoice API

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to check how the paypal invoice looks like when it send email to the payer, however, the api doesn't seem to send the email. In the api response, there's a Invoice Url, I was able to see it but it requires the payer to login. Does the API send an email to payer's email or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**From the PayPal Invoice API docs:**

> To use the Invoicing API to request payment, you start by making one of the Invoicing API calls to PayPal. Your customer receives the invoice via email and clicks on an included link to view the invoice on PayPal's website. Customers who have a PayPal account can log into their PayPal accounts to pay the invoice. Customers can also pay using a check, debit, or credit card.
>   (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/invoicing/gs_Invoicing/)

As long as the "ack" field in the JSON response from the API shows "success" as value, an email will be sent by the buyer. He or she has to click the link and login to complete the payment.

**Example JSON response:**

```
{
  "responseEnvelope": {
  "timestamp": "2011-06-16T:12:30.861-07:00",  
  "ack": "Success",
  "correlationId": "78733df04b1f0",
  "build": "1942837"
},
  "invoiceID": "INV2-C4AK-UU3J-5SCL-9KZY",
  "invoiceNumber": "1192",
  "invoiceURL": "invoiceURL"
}
```

so the answer to your question is **YES**;

Comment: In PayPal Sandbox, does it sends email to the buyer?

Comment: The Sandbox has a special-purpose email inbox for your testing, contained in the Sandbox itself. (http://bit.ly/JJxpLq)

Answer (score 1):

Try sending yourself (or another account you control) an invoice. This will give you an idea of what the invoice looks like.